# Run program when a context menu item is clicked

Tags: c++, windows, windows-7, windows-shell

How can I run a program when a context menu item in a shell extension is clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a CreateProcess function you can call. Look at [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)